# How to delete one element of a jquery element?

Tags: jquery, node.js, pug

For a chat web-app, I want to remove an element of a jquery element.

```
var value = $('#users').val();
$('#users').empty();
$('#users').append($(value.replace('<div>' + data.name + '</div>', '')));
```

That's what I currently tried, but I do not really know, how to get all those values I added before with .append(...).

So, I want to get all of them and remove/replace one of them.

```
$('#users').val() -> empty
$('#users').value -> undef.
```

Probably I can do this with .valueOf()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whatever `$('#users')` is, you can get its inner html code with `$('#users').html()`

however, you can add a class to each of your appendices:

```
"<div class='myAppendix'>" + data.name + "</div>"
```

you assign a custom class to them and call it 'myAppendix'

now when you want to retrieve those elements you simply do:

```
$('.myAppendix')
```

thats how you target all of them, with jQuery. now if you know specifically which one you want to remove, you can name the added class by the name of your data or something, like that:

```
"<div class='"+ data.name +"'>" + data.name + "</div>"
```

so when you target it with     `$('.data.name')` you will get the specific element that uve added.

then you can remove it. dont remember how, $(element).remove() or something...

Comment: Thanks, .html() is exactly what I was searching for! :-)